# Is the function $\ln (u(x))$ integrable when $u$ is bounded and positive?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Consider $\Omega$ an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  $ u \in L^{\infty} (\Omega)$ a positive function. My question is : the well defined function $\ln (u(x))$ is integrable?

Intuitively the answer is yes, because $\ln(x)$ is integrable on finite intervals. But I don't know how to prove or disprove.

Comment: In this case the answer is affirmative, but in the general case of $u \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, because of the relation $\ln(x)<x$ for all $x>0$. I'm not comfortable enough with analysis to be sure that this enough, though.

Comment: Unless I have made a simple mistake, $\Omega=(0,1)$ with $u(x)=e^{-1/x}$ is a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clayton](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357133/in-this-case-the-function-ln-ux-is-integrable#comment2759929_1357133) gave a counterexample:   $\Omega=(0,1)$ with $u(x)=e^{-1/x}$.

It's true that $\ln x$ is integrable (it tends to $-\infty$ quite slowly as $x\to 0^+$). But the function $u$ can  compensate for that by approaching $0$ very fast, and this is what $e^{-1/x}$ does.